# Example of BLE client using circuitpython on an esp32 s3

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, adafruit-circuitpython

Can anyone point me at an example of using circuitpython on an ESP32 S3 to act as BLE client? I have BLE server (written in C++) which the client can read sensor data from and write commands to. The circuitpython documentation on BLE on an esp32 is very unclear, is what I want to do even possible?